# Jquery else not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a responsive navigation:

```
       <header>
            <nav>
                <ul class="navigation">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">asd</a>             
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">asd</a>             
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">asd</a>             
                    </li>
                    <button type="button" id="showmenu"> << </button>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

Can't use toggle  for jquery since the button also disappers, so i tried another way, however the else statement is not executing

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            if(menu=1) {
            $('#showmenu').click(function(){
                $('nav ul li').hide()
                $('nav ul').css('width', '3%');
                menu = 2;
            });
            }
            else { 

                $('#showmenu').click(function() {
                $('nav ul ').show();
                $('nav ul').css('width', '100%');
                menu = 1;
                });
            }                       
        });
```

It's an inline navigation sliding to the left. I've seen a bunch of other example, but not a single one where the button hiding the menu is in the navigation. Got any suggestions on how to make this work? Used toggle before that, but the else statement still wouldnt execute. Here 's a JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qEtgR/7/

**Edit:** == operator doesn't change a thing, else statement still does not execute, neither does stating a global var menu.

Comment: `if(menu=1) {` ==> `if(menu==1) {`

Comment: where is `menu` defined? BTW in an `if` statement, you need the `==` operator.................

Comment: you are missing with few more code.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it works!.

Comment: if statement needs to be inside one event handler so you check every click

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qEtgR/10/  do a double click

Comment: @AlonEitan `if (menu==1) {` ==> `if(menu===1) {`

Comment: @JLRishe Yup, agreed. But since there is no need to check the type in the provided code, a `==` would work as well as `===`

Comment: What you're actually doing here is just binding events. You should check the `if( menu == 1)` part INSIDE the `$('#showmenu').click(function(){` event, and not bind the event based on the value of `menu`. This question was closed for no good reason

Comment: Here's a working jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/23mhdnnn/

Comment: Please show initialization code for `menu`.  Initial value of `menu` may be the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the issue :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        if(menu==1) { // "==" missed here
        $('#showmenu').click(function(){
            $('nav ul li').hide()
            $('nav ul').css('width', '3%');
            menu = 2;
        });
        }
        else { 

            $('#showmenu').click(function() {
            $('nav ul ').show();
            $('nav ul').css('width', '100%');
            menu = 1;
            });
        }                       
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the logic problem

Comment: Probably, but the code base he shared was having that error.

Answer (score 0):

Use equality operator

```
if(menu==1) {
```

Comment: I did try that, i tried putting menu as a global variable as well, the else statement still does not execute